# Elasticsearch: What's the best way to search for a word within a string AND get score?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch's PHP client and I find really difficult to return results **with scores** whenever I want to search for a word that is "hidden" within a string.

### This is an example:

I want to get all the documents where the field "file" has the word "anses" and files are named like this:
*axx14anses19122015.zip*

## **What I know about it**

I know I should tokenize those words, can't realize how to do it.
Also I've read about aggregations but I'm really new to ES and I have to deliver a working piece ASAP.

## **What I've tried so far**

- REGEXP: using regular expressions is very expensive and does not return any scores, which is a must-to-have in order to shrink results and bring the user accurate information.
- Wildcards: same thing, slow and no scores
- Own script where I have a dictionary and search for critical words using regexp, if match, create a new field within that matched document with the word. The reason is to create a TOKEN so in future searches I can use regular match with scores. Negative side: the dictionary thing was totally denied by my boss so I'm here asking for any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at full text searching? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I believe I need something else than that. Also please have in mind that you're posting a link to mysql website and this is kind of different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest in your case [nGram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) see the example
I will create a analyzer and a mapping for a doc type

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "tokenizer": {
            "ngram_tokenizer": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 4,
               "max_gram": 4,
               "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "term_vector": "yes",
               "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

after that I`ll insert a document using your file name

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "text_field": "axx14anses19122015"
}
```

now I`ll just will use a query match

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "text_field": "anses"
        }
    }
}
```

and will receive a reponse like this

```
{
   "took": 8,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.10848885,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.10848885,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "axx14anses19122015"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What i did?
i just created a nGram tokenizer that will explode our string in 4 characters terms and will index this terms separated and they will be searched when I search a part of the string.
To see more, read this article https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch
Hope it help!

Comment: Depending on the regular search term length, I would suggest changing the size of each gram since they are affecting the score.
Edit: Especially since in this example, the search term has 5 letters

Comment: This is a really good approach, I will give it a try no doubt about it. Thanks a lot, whenever I finish trying this out I'll leave my feedback.

Comment: Ok, I've tried it out with no success. I've created 2 new indices for testing purpose but is not finding any results like in your example. I'll keep searching and reading, thank you very much though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after trying -so- many times it worked. I'll share the solution just in case someone else needs it. Thank you so much to Waldemar, it was a really good approach and I still cannot see why it's not working.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://ipaddresshere/tokentest' -d 
'{ "settings": 
    { "number_of_shards": 1, "analysis" : 
          { "analyzer" : { "myngram" : { "tokenizer" : "mytokenizer" } },
            "tokenizer" : { "mytokenizer" : { 
                           "type" : "nGram", 
                           "min_gram" : "3", 
                           "max_gram" : "5", 
                           "token_chars" : [ "letter", "digit" ] } } } },  
      "mappings": 
            { "doc" : 
                  { "properties" : 
                         { "field" : { 
                          "type" : "string", 
                          "term_vector" : "yes", 
                          "analyzer" : "myngram" } } } } }'
```

Sorry for bad indentation, I'm really hurry but want to post the solution.

So, this will take any string from "field" and split it into nGrams with lenght 3 to 5. For example: "abcanses14f.zip" will result in:

abc, abca, abcan, bca, bcan, bcans, etc... until it reaches anses or a similar term which is matcheable and has a score related to it.